# Eclipse doesn't generate the .apt_generated folder for Butter Knife

Tags: android, eclipse, annotations, butterknife

I have carefully followed the instructions in [the official guide](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html) to enable annotations in my Eclipse ADT 3.8.

That is, *Annotation Processing* and *Factory Path* are properly configured:

[image: Annotation Processing]

[image: Factory Path]

My Android application compiles successfully. It runs too, of course, but I get obvious NPEs due to views that are expected to be initialized by Butter Knife stay `null`.

If I change the configuration to generate, say `.apt_generated_foo_bar`, Eclipse will create that folder. But empty.

Any ideas on how I can convince Eclipse to create the appropriate classes in `.apt_generated`?

Comment: Similar to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288054/butterknife-does-not-create-anything-in-apt-generated-directory/

Comment: Yes, it is. But in that case the problem was just that the project did not compile. That is not my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question (and answer) duplicates this one: [Butterknife does not create anything in .apt_generated directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288054/butterknife-does-not-create-anything-in-apt-generated-directory/26036084)

First you need to make sure you have an **Android** project and [not an **Android library**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/2) project because Butterknife handles library projects using [a different approach](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#library-projects).

To do this click `Project Properties` and go to the `Android` section. For further details see [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.htm):

Then check these settings in *project/.factorypath*:

```
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/PotlatchClient/libs/butterknife-5.1.2.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

*project/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.prefs*:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.aptEnabled=true
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.genSrcDir=.apt_generated
org.eclipse.jdt.apt.reconcileEnabled=true
```

*project/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs*:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.processAnnotations=enabled
```

Finally do a refresh in Eclipse and clean to do a full rebuild.

The problem with the other suggestion is changing the JDK to 1.7 means you can only target Kitkat (4.4) or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, 
changed: Project>Properties>JavaCompiler>CompilerComliance level from 1.6 to 1.7
 now Clean Project,
and it worked