# Android Butterknife - binding in fragment

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm using Butterknife for the first time but something must be wrong. I have a fragment and a Listview and a TextView just for testing but Butterknife wont bind my variables:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Bind(R.id.resultListView) ListView resultList;

    @Bind(R.id.textView1) TextView test;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        System.out.println(resultList); //null
        System.out.println(view.findViewById(R.id.resultListView)); //works
        System.out.println(test); //null
        System.out.println(view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)); //works
        return view;
    }

}
```

No exception or anything. Manual binding works so my Views must be there.

Comment: What do your dependencies look like?

Comment: I just have the Butterknife jar included.

Comment: ahh, so are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this project hasnt been updated yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Code-wise, that looks just fine. So based on the comments, it looks like you need to setup the annotation processing in Eclipse: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ide-eclipse.html

Comment: Thanks, this has been done but interestingly the generated folder is empty. I didn't see that but I guess that has something to do with it?

Comment: What if you do a clean build?

Comment: Same. I assume the annotation processor never gets called?

Comment: It sounds like it - perhaps this might be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26036146/60261

Comment: Thanks, my project looked just like that, but now it works after I restarted Eclipse fully. I guess Clean/Rebuild wasnt enough lol. After a restard Eclipse actually generated the files.

Answer (score 62):

This work for me:

Gradle

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Code

```
.
...

@BindView(R.id.text_input)
TextView text_input;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    text_input.setText("Lorem Ipsum");
...
.
```

Comment: I copied `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'` from another project but missed the `annoationProcesser`.  Once I added this line and re-sync the project, it works like a a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

also dont forget to release when you are finish :

```
 private Unbinder unbinder;
```

...

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.finalisation_step_fragment, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        //initialize your UI

        return v;
    }
```

...

```
   @Override public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }
```

Comment: I've never done this ever - is it specifically needed for fragments?

Comment: Yes, it is specifically needed for fragments since it has a different lifecycle. This is mentioned in the documentation.