# getView() null inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

**EDIT:** Yes I've sort of re-posted this but if you read the two posts, they both point to different issues with (hopefully) the same cause. In my other question, a particular widget is null. Here, the entire getView funtion is returning null.

I've been working on this for hours now. Can't find any reason. I can't post the entire fragment here but the following should make it clear.

```
@BindView(R.id.acService) AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteService;
@BindView(R.id.acAddress) AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteAddress;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    initialize();
    loadSkillsData();

    return view;
}

private void initialize()
{
    context = getActivity();
    util = new Util(context);
    requestService = new RequestService();
    geoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context, null);

    autocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(context, geoDataClient, BOUNDS_ONTARIO, null);
    autocompleteAddress.setAdapter(autocompleteAdapter);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

private void loadSkillsData()
{
    Realm realm = getRealm();
    UserModel user = realm.where(UserModel.class).findFirst();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestAPI.ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestAPI restApi = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
    Call<ResponseSkills> loginCall = restApi.getSkills(user.getServerUserId());
    loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseSkills>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseSkills> call, final Response<ResponseSkills> response)
        {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
            {
                if (response.body().getStatus())
                {
                    skillList = response.body().getSkillList();
                    ArrayAdapter<SkillModel> skillAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, skillList);
AutoCompleteTextView acService = getView().findViewById(R.id.acService);
                    acService.setAdapter(skillAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (response.body().getError())
                    {
                        default:
                            Toasty.error(context, response.body().getError());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } else
            {
                Toasty.error(context, getString(R.string.toast_experienced_a_problem)).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseSkills> call, Throwable t)
        {
            Toasty.error(context, getString(R.string.toast_experienced_a_problem)).show();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Layout: [image: XML]

On the line **AutoCompleteTextView acService = getView().findViewById(R.id.acService);**, I get a NPE saying that getView is returning null.

Why is this that so?

Comment: can you post error log ?

Comment: Do not post same question twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691490/view-null-inside-fragment.

Comment: same question twice. down voted

Comment: Perhaps your view hasn't finished inflating hence the NPE? Try attaching an onGlobalLayoutListener to your view and doing your view manipulation code in there.

Comment: @ThomasCook Oh wow that fixed it. Can you please tell me why the view is taking so long to inflate?

Comment: It's not really an issue with how long it takes, the issue is that you have no control over how long it takes or at what point the OS decides to do the layout of your view. There is a difference between inflating a view and having the view be fully measured out and ready to interact with. By adding the view tree observer, you sidestep this issue and have a guarantee that the view will be ready to interact with as the OS is calling back to let you know it's ready.

Comment: @ThomasCook If you could post this as an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691490/view-null-inside-fragment

Comment: @Asim - sure, I'll do that now